# How come the Javascript for my Rails button_to button doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having styling issues with my button.  Currently I have this:

```
<%= link_to t(:add_to_cart), '#', :onclick => "$(this).parent().submit(); return false;", :type => "button", :class => "button primary" %>
```

which renders this:

```
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="$(this).parent().submit(); return false;">Add To Cart</a>
```

when I change the link_to to a button_to, I've got this:

```
<%= button_to t(:add_to_cart), '#', :onclick => "$(this).parent().submit(); return false;", :type => "button", :class => "button primary" %>
```

which renders this:

```
<input class="button primary" onclick="$(this).parent().submit(); return false;" type="submit" value="Add To Cart">
```

Unfortunately, the javascript no longer works. I can see the obvious change in the markup, but why does this no longer work? I'm a designer that dabbles in Rails, so please be gentle!  Seems like this could be something pretty simple.  I did try :url => '#' on the button_to, which gave me other styling issues, so I reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you want to do with button ?

you use **$(this).parent().submit();** ---> in jquery this part of code **submit the form** but **button_to** do this **by default** why you add it ??

then you use **return false;** ----> this **prevent to submit form** in javascript   !!!

i hope i clarify something to you

Comment: Fantastic, that worked.  I removed the script and everything works as intended!